# Вывести старое и новое значение в триггере

Tags: sql, sql-server

Задание слудующее:
Написать триггер (ShowUpdatedInfo), который выполняет аудит изменения  данных в таблице Книги (Books). При изменении данных, необходимо вывести старое и новое значение для всех полей измененных записей.

Как записать в таблицу @Changes только те значения что изменились?

```
create table [Books]
(
[Id] int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
[Name] nvarchar(100) not null constraint CH_Books_Name check([Name]<>N''),
[Pages] int not null constraint CH_Books_Pages check([Pages]<>0),
[Price] money not null constraint CH_Books_Price check([Price]>=0)
);
go

create or alter trigger ShowUpdatedInfo
on [Books]
for update
as
begin
declare @Changes table ([oldName] nvarchar(50), [newName] nvarchar(50), [oldPages] int, [newPages] int, [oldPrice] money, [newPrice] money)

end
go
```

Comment: 1) Таблица создаётся не в триггере, а гораздо раньше, ещё на этапе проектирования БД. 2) Для проверки поля на изменённость тупо делаете `IF OLD.field != NEW.field THEN`. Проверяя все поля по одному.

Comment: а если за один раз будет удалено не одна запись, а несколько, как их все перебрать?

Comment: У Вас есть таблица INSERTED с новыми значениями, есть таблица DELETED со старыми значениями, у каждой записи есть некий первичный ключ. Тупо соединяете эти две таблицы (FULL OUTER JOIN) по равенству первичного ключа и неравенству одного поля, и получаете только те пары поле_ДО и поле_ПОСЛЕ, которые собственно поменялись. И всё это не глядя - в отчёт. Потом для другого поля... и так далее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT YourTable (Id, OldName, OldPages, OldPrice, [NewName], [NewPages], [NewPrice], Changed)
SELECT d.Id,
    d.[Name] AS OldName,
    d.[Pages] AS OldPages,
    d.[Price] AS OldPrice,
    i.[Name] AS [NewName],
    i.[Pages] AS [NewPages],
    i.[Price] AS [NewPrice],
    GETDATE()
FROM deleted d
    JOIN inserted i ON d.[Id] = i.[Id]
WHERE d.[Name] != i.[Name]
    OR d.[Pages] != i.[Pages]
    OR d.[Price] != i.[Price]
```